# Updating model in UI5, two-way data binding becomes one-way when using formatter

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

In my UI5-app, I have a table where each row contains a [`sap.m.Switch`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Switch), which is bound to the model via [`formatter`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8), since the data is coming from the DB as `1`/`0`, rather than `true`/`false`, and that, probably, breaks the default [two-way data binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/c72b922fdb59422496661000165d7ff1).

To update a data model upon the editing value of this switch, I implemented the following [`change`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Switch/events/change)-event:

```js
onChangeSwitch: function onChangeSwitch(oEvent) {
    let context = oEvent.oSource.getBindingContext();
    let itemIndex = context.sPath.substr(1);
    let oModel = this.getView().byId("idTablePersons").getModel();
    oModel.oData[itemIndex].isPersonActive = (oEvent.mParameters.state) ? 1 : 0;
    oModel.refresh();
}
```

It does work, but I'm not sure if it is a proper way to implement such logic. Is there a standard way to update a model after changing `sap.m.Switch` value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're approaching this the wrong way around. `sap.m.Switch` already has an attribute to indicate state which you can directly bind to a model.

```xml
<Switch state="{IsPersonActive}" />
```

Assuming you bound the items in the table to an unnamed model, that'll set the `IsPersonActive` flag on the bound line to `true` or `false` depending on the state of the switch.

This also means it'll come out with the switches in the correct state if certain `IsPersonActive` flags are already set to true or false in your entity sets.

---

> (…) the data is coming from the DB as `1`/`0`, rather than `true`/`false` (…).
>   Is there a standard way to update a model after changing `sap.m.Switch` value?

The two-way data binding fix from [https://embed.plnkr.co/wwQXf8bTuiTP4RlP](https://embed.plnkr.co/wwQXf8bTuiTP4RlP?show=index.html,model%2Ftype%2FNumericBoolean.js,preview):

**NumericBoolean.js** (minimal example):

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/model/SimpleType",
], Type => Type.extend('demo.model.type.NumericBoolean', {
  constructor: function() {
    Type.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  formatValue: iValue => !!+iValue,
  parseValue: bValue => bValue ? 1 : 0,
  validateValue: vValue => { /*validate...*/ },
}));
```

```xml
<Switch xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  core:require="{ NumericBoolean: 'demo/model/type/NumericBoolean' }"
  state="{
    path: '/1or0',
    type: 'NumericBoolean'
  }"
/>
```

**Important note:**
It's mandatory to keep the `validateValue` declaration even if the implementation is not provided, otherwise `sap.m.Switch` will not work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the problem is that I get the data for the `sap.m.Switch` from the DB as `1`/`0` rather than `true`/`false`, therefore I use a formatter, which, probably, breaks the binding.

Comment: @MikeB. Yes, when a `formatter` is in use, the binding mode becomes `"OneWay"`. In order to keep it in `"TwoWay"`, you'll have to create your own `type` that _formats_ `1` and `0` as `true`/`false`, and _parses_ `true`/`false` as `1`/`0`. Apparently, this was already planned: https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/0adfe5b4aa611d7c5f763c5b16b0ffd4e4ce418a/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/model/type/Boolean.js#L46.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann, thanks for the important info, I would mark your comment as a solution, in case you arrange your response as the answer. P.S. I will appreciate if you could provide some code snippet how to feed the `sap.m.Switch` with the custom `type`.

Comment: @MikeB I'd rather let Jorg enhance his answer so that his answer can be accepted.  Jorg: here is a small sample you could add for Mike: https://embed.plnkr.co/wwQXf8bTuiTP4RlP

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the formatter, use expression binding wherever possible, i.e. for switch attribute „state“ to map 0/1 to true/false.
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.34.9/docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html

But overall, I suggest to use a custom type (see above), as the same is the two-way binding solution without the need of an implemented change-event.