# Formatter function not working properly inside Input Control

Tags: sapui5, formatter

I need to highlight a few of the table's cell border colors on the basis of a condition and pre-fill it with some negative value. Then I need to `SAVE`/`POST` this value to proceed further.

`View.xml`

```xml
 <t:Column width="100px">
    <Label text="ActualQty"/>
    <t:template>
       <Input id="idInput" value="{ parts: [ {path: 'viewData>ACT_QTY'}, {path: 'viewData>MTART'} ], formatter: '._formatter.defaultInput' }">
            <customData>
                <core:CustomData key="colorclass" value="{path: 'viewData>MTART', formatter: '._formatter.formatCell'}" writeToDom="true"/>
            </customData>
       </Input>
    </t:template>
</t:Column>
```

`Formatter.js`

```js
formatCell: function (iValue) {
    try {
        iValue.toString();
    } catch (err) {
        iValue = "foo";
    }
    return iValue.toString();
},

defaultInput: function (iValue, iValue1) {

    if (iValue !== 0 && iValue1 === "HALB") {
        iValue = "-1";
        return iValue;
    } else {
        return iValue;
    }
}
```

`style.css`

```css
div[data-colorclass="HALB"] { 
    border: 4px solid #fdf6b1 !important;
}
```

Highlighting and the default value is appearing. But inside the controller, the input value is not coming.
If I remove parts and pass single input param to formatter function, it's working. But I need both the values to built my logic.

[image]

## Update

Now I am using Composite Binding to make the binding as Two-way.

`View.xml`

```xml
<Input id="idInput" value="{ parts: [ {path: 'viewData>ACT_QTY'}, {path: 'viewData>MTART'} ], type: '._Compound', formatter: '._formatter.defaultInput' }">
```

`Compound.js`

```js
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/model/CompositeType",
    "dismantling/bom/integration/model/type/Compound"
], CompositeType => CompositeType.extend('Compound', {
    constructor: function () {
        CompositeType.apply(this, arguments);
        this.bParseWithValues = true; // make 'parts' available in parseValue
    },

    formatValue: iValue => iValue,
    parseValue: bValue => bValue,
    validateValue: vValue => { /*validate...*/ },
}));
```

In the controller file, I am passing `Compound` type as `_Compound`. I am not getting any errors in the console.
Still, I am not able to get the formatter passed value inside the controller.

Comment: Now I understood, the formatter function will make it one-way binding. The link has a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484815/updating-model-in-ui5-two-way-data-binding-becomes-one-way-when-using-formatter) using custom type. But I am not able to create the Type for my case. Please guide.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "Inside the controller, the input value is not coming"? **How** are you trying to access that "input value" from the controller? Via the model? Or `byId()`?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann - There is a SAVE button in this view. Inside the SAVE button press event, I am trying to access this input value.                                  
`var oModel = this.getModel("viewData"); var data = oModel.getProperty("/ReturnTracker");`

Comment: Please check my [SCN thread](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13322272/sapui5-formatter-function-not-working-properly-ins.html) for the screen shot.

Comment: Here is my first attempt to apply your logic with `type` (i.e. TwoWay enabled): https://embed.plnkr.co/DI5b0vdfz6YCKmsI?show=model/type/MyCompositeType.js,preview:?sap-ui-xx-componentPreload=off. But as you can see, as soon as the user enters something other than `0`, the value gets formatted back to `-1` due to the `formatValue` function (the new value is stored in the model though). I guess what you wanted to achieve is to format the value to `-1` *only once* if it's initially not `0`?

Comment: I need to access this `-1` in my controller. This is not happening.

Comment: You need to specify what you exactly mean by "access this -1 in my controller" as it's too vague. Why do you need `-1` in the controller in the first place? I thought it's only for the formatter to display the default value. Please describe more what you're actually trying to achieve in the question (not in this comment section).

Comment: I have updated the question. In your Sample program, are you able to access this negative value in your view's controller file?

Comment: Still trying to understand.. What does the negative value have to do with *saving*? The changed value is stored in the model. If you're using an ODataModel, simply call `submitChanges` to send the changes to the back end. With a client-side model (e.g. JSONModel), you'll have to call `getProperty` with the resolved binding path as the argument. ... I feel we're having an [xy-poroblem](https://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: I have added the app snapshot in my [SCN thread](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13322272/sapui5-formatter-function-not-working-properly-ins.html) question section for clarity. on the Press of "Save Verify", this updated value is not reflecting inside my model.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann - In your updated sample code, are you able to display  ACT_QTY as `-1` instead of `42` in the initial load?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The sample shows already `-1` instead of `42` in the input field.

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann - I mean in the Input Description like `ACT_QTY: -1, MTART: HALB`

Comment: I just updated my sample. TwoWay binding awaiting user inputs will use the 3rd part as its default value initially (`-1`). If a `formatter` is used (e.g. in the `description`), the current limitation is that only one binding can be defined in that property since the binding needs to handle a state and the formatter cannot predict how many times it will be called (Currently, it's called as many times as the number of the bindings in that bound property. But that's an undocumented behavior which should be relied on).

Comment: Understood. then is there any way to update this value (`-1`) back into the model?

Comment: The changes from the input fields are stored in the model due to TwoWay binding.

Comment: The changes in the input will be updated in the model due to the TwoWay binding. That is fine. My requirement is to update this input value `-1` generated during the initial load.

Comment: That creates pending changes already before the user did a single change. It's not the responsibility of the client to manipulate the initial response. I highly recommend to talk with other project members (especially the backend guys) and to reconsider the current approach. Identify what the backend could do instead.

Comment: I agree that this can be handled in the backend. But as per business requirement, it should flow from UI to backend. This particular scenario needs, those input fields should display `-1` as per the validation, we have built. then during SAVE/POST, these table records will flow to backend.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatter is correct. Make sure sure that the values are actually accessible under your binding path and that the formatter is accessible to the view. If both these things are ensured, your function will work just fine.

Comment: everything is working perfectly. still not getting the formatted value inside the controller.